# What is the bad case in greedy algorithm for coin changing algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

The Coin changing problem is making change for n cents using the fewest number of coins.

Can you give a set of coin denominations for which the greedy algorithm does not yield an optimal solution. The set should include a penny so that there is a solution for every n.

Comment: The question resemble a school exercise for homework

Comment: I won't add another answer but will mention that this can't happen in a good monetary system. This means that for systems like 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50 etc greedy algorithm is the best one.

Comment: @xenteros the greedy algorithm may fail even in a good monetary system in cases where you do not have an infinite supply of coins or bills. See my example below. This definitely looks like a school homework problem. I was talking about this with my son, and it took a little thinking to come up with an example of a greedy solution not working.

Answer (score 7):

Well, given `10, 7, 1` coins change `15`:

```
15 = 10 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 // greedy  (6 coins)
15 =  7 + 7 + 1             // optimal (3 coins)
```

You can easily generate a greedy solution as much *inefficient* as you want:
just let available coins be `1`, `N-1`, `N` and try to change `2 * N - 2`:

```
 N, 1, 1, ..., 1 // greedy  (N - 1 coins)
 N-1, N-1        // optimal (2 coins)
```

Now, make `N` being large

Comment: Nice answer, the first example is very clear! However, I think the last example would not yield the inefficient case, because a greedy algorithm would try: N + (N - 1) instead of N + 1 + 1 + ... + 1. Also, the optimal solution would be N + (N - 1), which is equal to 2 * N - 1. I think if we try to change X, the inefficient solution would be choosing amongst the coins: `floor(X/2) + 2, floor(X/2), 1`. E.g.: X = 123, the coins would be: 63, 61, 1. The greedy solution would be: 63 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1, and the optimal solution would be: 61 + 61 + 1.

Comment: @mateleco: I'm sorry for the typo: the sum to exchange should have been `2 * N - 2`.

Comment: Okey, after your edition it now makes sense. However, as a side note, your general solution leads to decimal coins if we are trying to change an odd amount of money. But, I don't mean to be picky, just to point it out for the record. Thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Coins:** 1, 5, 8
**Amount:** 10
**Greedy solution:** 8, 1, 1 (3 coins)
**Optimal:** 5, 5 (2 coins)

---

To expand on @xenteros comment have a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem#Greedy_method) (where btw. you would have found an example):

> For the so-called canonical coin systems, like the one used in US and
>   many other countries, a greedy algorithm of picking the largest
>   denomination of coin which is not greater than the remaining amount to
>   be made will produce the optimal result. This is not the case for
>   arbitrary coin systems, though: if the coin denominations were 1, 3
>   and 4, then to make 6, the greedy algorithm would choose three coins
>   (4,1,1) whereas the optimal solution is two coins (3,3).

Answer (score 0):

The greedy algorithm will not always work when the number of coins available is finite. Lets say you have the following in a cash register:

- $50: 3 bills
- $10: 11 bills
- $5: 6 bills
- $1: 9 bills
- Quarters: 55 coins
- Dimes: 47 coins
- Nickels: None
- Pennies: 4 coins

A customer comes in and buys candy worth 69 cents, pays with a $1 bill and needs to be given 31 cents in change.

The greedy algorithm will pick a quarter first and will then need to pick 6 cents more. There are no nickels and there are only 4 pennies. So it will fail to find the correct change. The correct change (3 dimes and 1 penny) can be found using dynamic programming.